# Angular/Ionic hides data attributes (data-***) in the imported HTML through REST services

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, rest

Within my Angular App, I am importing HTML through RESTful services. While all the HTML is properly retrieved, yet for some reason Angular hides the data attributes `data-url` or even `id` from each element.

Is there any reason behind that and can I stop that?

Thanks

Comment: How are you inserting the HTML string into the DOM?

Comment: In my `.html` file, like this `<div class="EBScontent" ng-bind-html="what.body"></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller add this:

```
$scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
}
```

And in your view:

```
<div class="EBScontent" ng-bind-html="to_trusted(what.body)"></div>
```